# encryptionCertificateId of Microsoft API

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks, microsoft365

I'm trying to register a webhook for microsoft teams in order to get an update once a message is sent over some chat.
Apparently the way to do that according to [Microsoft API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data), is to send a request with "encryptionCertificate" as following:
[image]
Now I'm trying to figure out what should go in the encryptionCertificate field but I have failed to find a clear answer in the documentation.
The only thing I figured is that the field contain a base64 encoded "Certificate", which leads me to the same question.
What is this certificate and how do I find it.

Anybody who has some experience with MS APIs or knows anything about that and can help ?
Much appreciated guys

Here's also some naive tries that I have attempted and what are their results:

1. "encryptionCertificate": "YWJjZGVmZw==", resulted in : Certificate validation error: Cannot find the requested object,
2. "encryptionCertificate": "klsjdaadnkjadn", Certificate validation error: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string
3. "encryptionCertificate": null, , Certificate cannot be empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`encryptionCertificate` contains base 64 encoded value of the public key.

The requirements for public key are:

- The key must be of type RSA
- The key size must be between 2048 and 4096 bits
- Export the certificate in base64-encoded X.509 format and include only the public key

For example, by using `openssl` commands

```
openssl genrsa -out private.key 1024
openssl req -new -x509 -key private.key -out publickey.cer -days 365
openssl pkcs12 -export -out public_privatekey.pfx -inkey private.key -in publickey.cer
```

It generates a private key, creates a X509 certificate (.cer file) and exports x509 certificate and private key to a pfx file.

When you create a subscription with `encryptionCertificate` read the entire `publickey.cer` file (including the -- Begin certification / End certificate portions) and set base64-encoded content to `encryptionCertificate` property.

Resources:

[Managing encryption keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data#managing-encryption-keys)